# How can I use noexcept when I select a specific hidden function from my inheritance list?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14

In order to avoid repeating similar function definitions, I use the fact that inherited members with the same name are hidden and can be selected/differentiated by using a specific base class qualifiers:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<template<class, class> class CreatePolicy, class Base, class... Derived>
class factory : public CreatePolicy<Base, Derived>...
{
public:
    template
    <
        class T,
        std::enable_if_t
        <
            !std::is_same<Base, T>::value && std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, int
        > = 0
    >
    std::unique_ptr<Base> create() noexcept( noexcept( CreatePolicy<Base, T>::create() ) )
    {
        return CreatePolicy<Base, T>::create();
    }
};
```

Using it looks like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

template<class Base, class Derived>
struct create_t
{
    auto create()
    {
        return std::make_unique<Derived>();
    }
};

struct base
{
    virtual void print() const noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "base\n";
    }
};

struct derived : public base
{
    virtual void print() const noexcept override
    {
        std::cout << "derived\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    factory<create_t, base, derived> f;
    auto d = f.create<derived>();
    d->print();
}
```

While this compiles under VC++2015, GCC5.1 is giving me this error due to the `noexcept` specification of `create()`:

> ```
> ..\main.cpp|20|error: cannot call member function 'auto
> create_t<T>::create() [with T = derived]' without object|
> ```

How can I make this compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> create() noexcept( noexcept( std::declval<CreatePolicy<Base, T>&>().create() ) )
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e18afdf47bcb9aa3).

You only get the implicit `this->` within the body of the method.  Msvc regularly gets template expansion wrong, so I will presume them guilty unless proven otherwise.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is rejected by GCC other than that it has a bug? It looks like valid C++. At instantiation, it should be transformed to implicit class member access

Comment: @joha I know of no reason why an implicit `this->` would be assumed in that context.  That usually only happens in bodies of member functions.  MSVC template instantiation code is pretty quirky and non-compliant, so I would assume they screwed up as usual.

Comment: The implicit this should be added wherever "this" can be used, and it should be added when instantiating the template in the instantiation context (looked it up because this part changed frequently recently due to defects). So an implicit this should be added here IMHO. The transformation happens in all "members" (also NSDMIs), so also in noexcept specifiers because "this" can be used there, and at that time the code is valid, so the compiler can't reject it at template definition time. IMHO OPs code is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `base_class::method(...)` to call a member function of the base class only works within the body of member functions. This specifically excludes the unevaluated contexts like they occur within the `noexcept` specification. The beauty of these contexts, though, is that they are just that: Not evaluated. So you can just get an instance of your class somehow and call the method on that. The standard way to do this is using `std::declval`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> create() noexcept( noexcept( std::declval<CreatePolicy<Base, T>&>().create() ) )
```